# nivo slider error pauseTime under 2000

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I'm trying to use nivo slider in a template but have stumbled on this:

If the pauseTime value is smaller than the 3000 (as in the demo code) then the timing is completely off. It just jumps from slide to slide. Has anyone stumbled upon this or is it just me?

All of this using the default params and code (copy paste from http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/)